# Is cantillation with Kriyat Shema required?

Tags: halacha, shema, trop-cantillation, stringency-chumrah, rabbeinu-yonah

Is one required to recite Kriyat Shema with the tune of Torah reading? I know it says so in [Talmidei Rabbenu Yonah on the Rif Brachoth 8b](https://www.sefaria.org/Rif_Berakhot.8b.3?lang=he&p2=Rabbeinu_Yonah_on_Berakhot.8b.6&lang2=he&w2=all&lang3=he), however, as someone who learned Hebrew later in life, it is difficult for me to focus on precise pronunciation with the cantillation. Obviously, it is the ideal, but is it a halachic requirement?

Comment: What is "Yonah 8b"?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to be more clear. It was a reference to Talmidei Rabbenu Yonah which is a source that was cited elsewhere. I know the Tur and Shulchan Aruch share this view, however, apparently Rama says that the Minhag Ashkenaz is not to say it with cantillation.

Comment: I'm guessing your source for the "Talmidei Rabbenu Yonah 8b" is [cite note 60](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Kriyat_Shema#cite_note-60) to Halachipedia's _Kriyat Shema_ article. I think they mean [Talmid Rabbenu Yonah's commentary to Rif's Berachot 8b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rif_Berakhot.8b.6?lang=he&p2=Rabbeinu_Yonah_on_Berakhot.8b.6&lang2=he): "**אומרים שמע ישראל ולא היו מפסיקין**. כלומר שלא היו קורין אותה בנחת עם הטעמים שלה כמו שאנו נוהגין היום _שעיקר מצות ק"ש הוא לקרותה עם הטעמים שלה_" (italic emphasis mine).

Comment: One should also know the correct dikduk of every word to make sure one understands it properly.

Answer (score 5):

The Mishnah Berura 61:38 says clearly that one shouldn’t say with the cantillations if it will take away from his concentration

> בכך - ובלבד שיכוין כי הנגינה למי שלא הורגל בה מפסיד הכונה:

https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.61.37?lang=bi

Comment: (1) The Mishnah Berura's comment may only be relevant for where it is not obligatory (i.e. in Ashkenazi communities), for those who non-the-less choose to be מדקדקים about it (the s.v. בכך is for the end of Rema's gloss). (2) Based on Mishnah Berura's previous comment (61:37, s.v. כן), one shouldn’t say it with _the melody_ (הנגינה) of the cantillation, if it will take away from his concentration. One is still be obligated to make sure to pause in the proper places: "אך שצריך ליזהר לפסוק במקום הראוי להפסיק לפי הענין כדי שיהיה טעם והבנה לדבריו".